# ADAL iOS: Instance method in category overrides method from class (linker warning)

Tags: ios, adal, linker-warning

### My setup:

I'm using [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) via cocoapods in my iOS project.

Xcode: 9.2

ADAL: 2.5.4

### The devastating warning of immense concern:

When building I get this warning:

> instance method 'speInfo' in category from
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mobile-echesuhdqeeauvgypmfgbpnmnsjl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ADAL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ADTokenCacheItem+Internal.o
>   overrides method from class in
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mobile-echesuhdqeeauvgypmfgbpnmnsjl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ADAL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ADTokenCacheItem.o

### Woe is me!

I tried cleaning the derived data folder and doing a clean in Xcode, it didn't help. I also updated ADAL from 2.5.2 to 2.5.4 (pod install), it didn't help as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added `-Xlinker -no_objc_category_merging` to the `Other Linker Flags` and the warning was suppressed.

[image]